# Merging watermark using PyPDF2 causes all pages to merge together into one instead of page by page merging

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a pdf document 'sample_doc1.pdf' and a watermark file (created from word document) 'watermark.pdf'. When i try to merge them in python using PyPDF2, I expect the following results:

[image: Expected result]

However, I keep getting a result where all the pages get merged together (shown below). Note that the PDF still registers as 2 pages (a small white box below is being registered as a "page").

[image]

My full code is as follows:

```
writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

with open(main_file, 'rb') as fileinput:
    pdf_file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fileinput)

    with open('watermark.pdf', 'rb') as filewatermark:
        watermark_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filewatermark)

        for page in range(pdf_file.getNumPages()):
            current_pdf_page = pdf_file.getPage(page)
            first_page_watermark = watermark_pdf.getPage(0)
            first_page_watermark.mergePage(current_pdf_page) # -- (12) : Base layer = first_page_watermark; Top layer = current_pdf_page
            writer.addPage(first_page_watermark) # -- (13)

            with open("output.pdf", 'wb')as file_output:
                writer.write(file_output)
```

However, when I change the order of layers in the code (in line -- (12) and (13) ), I managed to make it better but the watermark appears on top of the text.

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to do the other way round. The watermark should be what you call `pdf_file`

Comment: @cards that isn't working and gives the same result as the case mentioned above.

Comment: @KJ agreed. Employer requires it and it's unnecessarily time consuming to do it for 10s of documents every week so im trying to automate it.